# Cannot see RDLC code tab in SSRS visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I am doing some SSRS examples from a book. The book shows several tabs in visual studio - app.config, report1.rdlc (This is XML code for report1) , form1.designer.vb, form1.resx, report1.rdlc[design] (This is a graphical table/gui form of report1).

But after following all the steps, I only see these tabs - Report1.rdlc[Design], Form1.vb[Design]. Why can't I see a tab showing my rdlc file in XML form, even when I followed the steps in the book. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its all about getting lucky and using the right words in google. I looked at the report1.rdlc[design] tab and thought of "design view" (In eclipse, its called perspective). Googled - "visual studio rdlc view xml" This link gave it all - http://forums.asp.net/t/1387710.aspx?Report+Viewer+rdlc+files+only+in+design+view+developer+view+

**Here are the steps -**

```
Visual Studio > Select the report1.rdlc tab > View > Open With > XML Editor > ok.
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013:

- Right-click the .rdlc file in Solution Explorer
- Click "Open With..."
- Select "XML (Text) Editor" and click OK